# How can I remove certain HTML tags from the RSS feed?

Tags: tags, rss, feed

One news aggregator wants to have RSS feed without any links into the `<description>` field. So I try to use this code in `functions.php` to remove `<a href></a>` tags, but it doesn’t work. What’s wrong? How can I remove the tags but keep intact all the text?

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_custom_feed');
function my_custom_feed( $content ){
    global $post;

    if ( ! is_feed() )
        return $content;

    // Remove all shortcodes
    $content = strip_shortcodes( $post->post_content );
        $content = strip_tags( $content );

    // Remove all html tags, except these
    $my_allowed_tags = array(
        'p'      => array(),
        'strong' => array(),
        'em'     => array(),
        'img'    => array( 'src' => array(), 'width' => array(), 'height' => array() ),
    );
    $content = wp_kses( $content, $my_allowed_tags );

    // Balance tags
    $content = balanceTags( $content, true );

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Above code is working well. The problem was with caching plugin.
Shame on me.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how it doesn't work :)

Does it remove some links or doesn't do anything at all. Anyway, to alter the content of every RSS item you can use [rss_item()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rss_item/) hook, or [rss2_item()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rss2_item/) depending which stream is your target.

```
add_filter('rss_item', 'custom_item_content');
function custom_item_content($content) {

    //  alter your $content here

    return $content;
}
```